# Keyboard issue with iOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, becomefirstresponder, ios-4.2

My app works as supposed on an iPhone running iOS 4.1 but not on iOS 4.2. I have an UIInputField set to first responder but the keyboard does not show up. The becomeFirstResponder is called in the viewDidLoad method. Is it a bug or has Apple made drastic changes? I'm using Xcode 3.2.5.

Answer (score 2):

Does the input field have User Interaction Enabled?  This is now required in iOS 4.2.

Comment: by required I mean in prior versions, becomeFirstResponder would work with this disabled....apparently this changed in iOS 4.2

Answer (score 1):

`-viewDidLoad` is called when your view is first initialized, not necessarily when it's displayed. Try calling `-becomeFirstResponder` inside `-viewDidAppear:` instead:

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];

     [myField becomeFirstResponder];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a thread at the Apple Developer Forums (https://devforums.apple.com/message/325348#325348) where a solution was described. Set the UITextField property userInteractionEnabled to YES before a call to becomeFirstResponder is made, preferably in the viewDidLoad method.